# Porting Program From Linux to Windows: Using cstr

Tags: c++, linux, string, windows-10, porting

I'm trying to port a program from Linux to Windows 10. I have the source, and there are references to the type "cstr" like the following:

```
cstr filename = sourceline->sourcefile;
```

I don't think the Windows SDK defines this type (its flagged as undefined in the code). Can I just replace it with standard C++ string definitions like:

```
std::string filename;
```

Or does cstr have other properties that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Why don't you start by looking up what `cstr` *actually is* on the original platform? (It's not a standard type)

Comment: Can you identify where the definition of `cstr` comes from?

Comment: I've actually been unable to find it: it's not listed in the gcc library reference, and when I google it, I get discussions about c_str and CStr, which aren't the same thing. I was hoping someone here knew where it came from.

Comment: Please provide a reference or link to the program you are porting.

Comment: Here's a link to the code: you can see the "cstr" near the top, after all the comments and includes: https://pastebin.com/5GhUwBMB

Comment: OP here: it turns out that cstr is something the original programmer defined in an external library file that wasn't included in the git repository. I had to download it separately, but that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of your `cstr` type. However, when you port your code to Windows, you should pay attention to your file name strings, in particular to their *encoding*.

It's common to use UTF-8 on Linux; but on Windows the *"native"* Unicode encoding used in Win32 APIs is **UTF-16**. So, if you use `std::string` to store UTF-8 encoded strings in your Linux C++ code, you should remember to convert those from UTF-8 to UTF-16 on Windows, before passing them to Win32 APIs.

You can use the `std::wstring` class in your Windows-specific C++ code (or even the `CStringW` class from ATL; you are already writing platform-specific code here, so using non-standard non-portable classes in Windows-specific portions of code should not be an issue).

It's a common pattern for *cross-platform* C++ code to use UTF-8 in the portable cross-platform portions of code, and convert to UTF-16 at the Windows API boundaries.

In addition, you may find [this MSDN Magazine article *"Unicode Encoding Conversions with STL Strings and Win32 APIs"*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt763237) of interest.